# Rejecting TCP packets from certain IP on network using iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall

Say I wanted to reject packets that are sent to my computer from a specific IP on the network using iptables. Do I need to define the destination of the packet in my command or is it sufficient to just include the source?

For example, say I am working on 126.184.25.25 and I want to reject all TCP packets from 126.184.25.101 should I use:

```
 sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -s 126.184.25.101 -d 126.184.25.25  -j REJECT
```

or is it sufficient to remove the destination address and use:

```
sudo iptables -t filter -A INPUT -p tcp -s 126.184.25.101 -j REJECT
```

When testing both of the above on my network, the former appeared not to work, but both seem to make sense and I am unsure as to why the former may be incorrect.

Comment: Is there a NAT involved in this network?

Comment: I believe there might, however this was on a machine on my University network and I am unsure of their setup unfortunately. How might this affect my results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do I need to define the destination of the packet in my command or is it sufficient to just include the source?

No and yes it is. If you leave off a setting it has a default. If you don't specify a protocol it defaults to block all, if you don't specify the table (-t) it defaults to filter.

The man page normally states the default setting, if it has one.

Answer (score 0):

To reject all tcp packets from the source address:

> sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 126.184.25.101 -j REJECT

It is not necessary to specify the destination, and in some cases (ie. broadcast packets) wouldn't work.

What this says is for your INPUT chain, (-I)insert this rule at the top.
  For traffic from (-s) source address, (-j) target traffic to the DROP rule.

DROP may preferable over REJECT, because reject sends a response back, while drop, um.. drops the packet, without responding.

Also, if you want to drop all protocols, (tcp,udp,icmp, etc...) remove the "-p tcp" like so:

> sudo iptables -I INPUT -s ipaddress -j DROP

There may be implications to your network situation, where DROP would cause trouble, and then REJECT may be a better choice.

Also, note that this will not live beyond the current os running cycle.  If permanency is needed, you will need to research more.

Comment: This is great and all, however does not really answer the question I have posed.